# Error when clipping multiple rasters

Tags: arcpy, clip, error-000800, error-000628, error-000622

I am trying to clip about 36 rasters by a polygon. However, I am running into an error. It isn't a coding problem with the loop because I receive the same error when I run the function on a single raster. Here is my code:

```py
# Import system modules
import arcpy
import os

# Set environment settings
arcpy.env.workspace = r"H:\GIS Project\reprojected_rasters" #The file where your files are
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
outWorkspace = r"H:\GIS Project\clipped_rasters" #where you want the new rasters to go
arcpy.env.parallelProcessingFactor = "50"
clipping_shp = r"H:\GIS Project\large AF dataset\point_feature_class\clipping.shp"
rasters = arcpy.ListRasters("*","TIF")
print rasters

arcpy.Clip_management ("SND_100_200_EV_N_P_AU_NAT_C_20140801.tif", "131.183300 -37.714100 152.250000 -16.056200", r"H:\GIS Project\clipped_rasters" , clipping_shp, "ClippingGeometry" , "NO_MAINTAIN_EXTENT")

print "Clipped Script ran ok"
```

However, when I try to run this code, I receive the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<module2>", line 21, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.3\ArcPy\arcpy\management.py", line 13594, in Clip
    raise e
ExecuteError: ERROR 000622: Failed to execute (Clip). Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000800: The value is not a member of ClippingGeometry | NONE.
```

Here is some information about my data:

- all are .tif files
- all are projected into the same datum (GDA 1994 Australian Albers)
- The clipping polygon was made from using the minimum extent function of a point feature class

Comment: Is clipping.shp in geographical coordinates? Are your rasters geographical coordinates? Are all the spatial references defined? Your code looks reasonable, the only thing I can think of is that a geographical extent doesn't agree with a projected dataset; as the extent *"131.183300,-37.714100,152.250000,-16.056200"* isn't specified in any CRS it may disagree with the CRS of the shapefile or raster.

Comment: Yes clipping.shp and all rasters are in GDA 1994.

I retrieved the extent from the arcgis desktop in layer properties under source.

Comment: Is the error happening during the first iteration in your `for` loop?  If so, then you can reduce your code snippet by eliminating that loop.  The less code you have and present in a code snippet the more likely it is that you or a potential answerer will spot what is astray.

Comment: If it's the extent of the layer can you try arcpy.Clip_management(inrl,arcpy.Describe(clipping_shp).extent,... as an extent object http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018z00000072000000 instead of a string; it shouldn't matter but I find a numeric list is less prone to cause errors.

Comment: Sadly, this did not work. I have another error now. I have posted the new error in the question

Comment: What error do you get once you remove commas? Now, you are trying to assign clipping shape parameter to an `arcpy.extent` object, which is incorrect. It expects a string of coordinates of lower left and upper right coordinates, as you did before!

Comment: It throws the same error. ERROR 0008000: The value is not a member of ClippingGeometry

Comment: @PolyGeo I took the loop out completely and tried the execute the function on one raster, and it throws the same error. This must mean that I have either correctly inputted something or my rasters are not aligned.

The raster resolution has nothing to do with the clipping function, correct?

Comment: I cannot remember the last time that I clipped a raster.  If you "took the loop out completely and tried the execute the function on one raster, and it throws the same error" then I think you should overhaul the code snippet that you are presenting.  I suspect it should become just a few lines plus `print` statements to show values of all variables used.

Comment: @Douglas, see my update. You are missing `nodata_value` argument!

Comment: try running the shape file through repair geometry tool then try the clip?

Comment: Your shp file’s folder name says point_feature_class and if the geometry type for your clipping shape is a point, it will not work. Better to check this out.

Answer (score 1):

You are going to laugh at that but if you replace the commas with whitespaces in your rectangle extent string and if you add missing argument for `nodata_value`, it should work, e.g.,:

`arcpy.Clip_management (inrl, "131.183300 -37.714100 152.250000 -16.056200", outrl, clipping_shp, nodata_value="0" "ClippingGeometry" , "NO_MAINTAIN_EXTENT")`

Comment: Sadly, this did not work. I have another error now. I have posted the new error in the question